# Add value of array to input

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have data that came from the back-end and its writing to form, this is an array of objects

Here is code

```
 this.companyDetailsForm = new FormGroup({
        directors : new FormControl(response?.companyDirectors)
    });
```

Then in HTML I make ngFor for it like this

```
 <div *ngFor="let director of companyDetailsForm.controls['directors'].value; let i = index" class="form-group start-aligned" style="margin-left: 69px;margin-right: 69px">
                            <label>{{'Director' | localize}} {{i+1}}</label>
                            <input disabled type="text" class="form-control" pInputText formControlName="director.name" />
                        </div>
```

Here is how the director looks like

```
{ "id": 51, "name": "DIRECTOR, Test" }
```

I need to add name field data to input, how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Since `response?.companyDirectors` is an array type then `directors` is not `FormGroup` its a `FormArray`.

```
directors : new FormArray(response?.companyDirectors)
```

https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-form-array/

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in other answer, as you have an array, you want a `FormArray`. I like to use `FormBuilder`, but it is not a must. If you are getting the data async, you can use `setControl` to add the director names. So I would suggest the following:

```ts
companyDetailsForm!: FormGroup;

constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {
  this.companyDetailsForm = this.fb.group({
    directors: this.fb.array([])
  });
}
```

and when you get the data, map the names from your array:

```ts
this.companyDetailsForm.setControl(
  'directors',
  this.fb.array(response && response.companyDirectors && response.companyDirectors.map(x => x.name))
);
```

Then in template you iterate the form array and use the index as the form control:

```html
<div formArrayName="directors">
  <div *ngFor="let director of directorsArr; let i = index">
    <input [formControlName]="i">
  </div>
</div>
```

`directorsArr` is just a `getter` for your formarray:

```ts
get directorsArr() {
  return (this.companyDetailsForm.get('directors') as FormArray).controls;
}
```

**[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glauqy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)** for your reference.